# MultiValueField django unexpected keyword argument error

Tags: django

I want to set field to enter concentration and the units for it.  
So I have in my model:

```
class Cbc(models.Model):
...
    hgb = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

in my form:

```
class CbcForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
    class Meta:
        field_classes = {
            'hgb' : ConcentrationField,
            }
...
 23 class ConcentrationField(forms.MultiValueField):
 24     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
 25         _widget = WidgetConcentration
 26         fields = (
 27                 forms.IntegerField,
 28                 forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('g/L', 'g/L'), ('g/dL', 'g/dL')), initial='g/L'),
 29                 )
 30         super().__init__(fields=fields, widget = _widget, **kwargs)
 31
 32     def compress(self, values):
 33         if values[1] == 'g/dL':
 34             return values[0] * 10
 35         return values[0]
```

but I have an error:

```
 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_value'
```

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: Show the full traceback. And what is WidgetConcentration?

Comment: You're passing a wrong attribute to some initialiser, but not showing the line of code where the error actually happens. Please check in your trackback which lines of code are involved in your error, or show us the full traceback